# How determine if an application is a web application in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

My code is in a process that might be a Console application, a desktop application, or an ASP.NET application. I'm trying to find out which kind of application I'm running in.

For .NET framework, I can use `HostingEnvironment.IsHosted` to see if I'm running in ASP.NET.
But how do I determine this for a .NET Core application? Note that it can be both in IIS and self hosted.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to know that? How would that change the app's behavior? After all, all types of apps use the same Generic host

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm developing a profiler and I need to extract metadata about the process I'm profiling.

Comment: Which is something done from the *outside* of a process, using .NET Core's built-in APIs like EventCounters and EventPipe. Otherwise the profiler will end up profiling itself

Comment: You can chek the source of tools like [dotnet-counters](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/tree/master/src/Tools/dotnet-counters) and [dotnet-trace](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/tree/master/src/Tools/dotnet-trace) to see how they work. The [Diagnostics and Instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/) section in the docs explains the APIs, tools, and available technologies

Comment: BTW I don't think having a built-in profiler in the application is bad. That's something Windows in general and .NET specifically always paid attention to. All versions had profiling hooks, performance counters and APIs that allowed diagnostics collection with minimal overhead. Developers were simply too lazy to use them - reporting a metric takes more work than just dumping a string to a file while using 100x-1000x more CPU cycles

Comment: So having your own tool *alongside* the app makes sense. There's even a [discussion on how to collect diagnostics from a side-car container](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/issues/810) -  not whether it's possible but documenting the process

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess I can use the profiling API (don't know) but that seems like an overkill. Since I run my own code in the same process, I was hoping for an in-process solution.

Comment: Overkill is what you're trying to do - and overhead. In fact, what are you trying to do? Why not use the built-in tools? How do you expect to profile the application if you don't use the built-in mechanisms? Remember, the application *already* publishes metrics about CPU, RAM, garbage collections etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The biggest thing the profiling API allows me to do is to instrument the code and inject my own code.

Comment: When I want to know about the things that a website uses, I try this website: https://builtwith.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am doing it.  Might not work in everyones use case but this works for me.

```
        var webType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core");
        RunningAsWebApp = webType != null && Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.ExportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => webType.IsAssignableFrom(x)) != null;
```